# Systematic approach to solve logical problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I came across following [problem and corresponding solution](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps102/spring06/assign/hw01-sol.pdf):

> [image]

When I tried it myself I was not able to come up with the solution, especially the contrapositive step. May be because never in the past I tried rewriting given sentences in another (contrapositive) form and solve from there. So I was guessing can there be any non-tricky approach to solve such problems. My go to approach is to utilise resolution refutation. I came up with following clauses:

1. $\neg m\vee i \quad\text{(from P1)}$
2. $m \vee \neg i \quad \text{(from P2)}$
3. $m \vee l \quad \text{(from P2)}$
4. $\neg i \vee h \quad \text{(from P3)}$
5. $\neg l\vee h \quad \text{(from P3)}$
6. $\neg h\vee g \quad \text{(from P4)}$

($m$ for mythical, $i$ for immortal, $l$ for mammal, $h$ for horned, $g$ for magical)
To this I added $\neg m$, $\neg h$, $\neg g$ and tried to derive empty clause / $FALSE$. But I was not able to. **Q1.** Is this enough?

**Q2.** Is there any systematic / less tricky approach to solve such problems?

Comment: IMO, the final statement of the problem is wrong: Horned and Magical are Ok, but "there is no way to show the unicorn is Mythical." 7. must be Magical.

Comment: yes I realised that too. Added link of source pdf. But I guess my questions remain unanswered?

Comment: Systematic but very tedious: truth table. In other words, consider all $32$ possible assignments of truth values to the five relevant properties (mythical, mortal, magical, mammal, horned); then go through the given information and eliminate those assignments that violate that information; finally see what remains.

Comment: I think the author of the quoted solution was having a bad day: *"so the $u$ is $A$ or $B$. However there is no way to show that the $u$ is $B$"*. Or maybe this follows from mythological rather than logical reasoning $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The clauses you have written are ok*.

Now, we have to use [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_propositional_logic) to derive that it is Horned and Magic.

For Horned we need the first three premises with the negation of the purported conclusion: $\lnot h$:

1. $¬m ∨ i$
2. $m ∨ ¬i$
3. $m ∨ l$
4. $¬i ∨ h$
5. $¬l ∨ h$
6. $¬h$ --- negated conclusion
7. $i \lor l$ --- from 1) and 3)
8. $l \lor h$ --- from 7) and 4)
9. $h$ --- from 8) and 5)

> 10. $\square$ --- from 6) and 9)

Now, having proved $h$ from P1)-P3), we can use P4) $\lnot h \lor g$ to prove Magic:

1. $h$
2. $\lnot h \lor g$
3. $\lnot g$ --- negated conclusion
4. $g$ --- from 1) and 2)

> 5. $\square$ --- from 3) and 4).

---

We cannot prove that it is Mythical. If we add $\lnot m$ to the set of clauses, we cannot produce the empty clause.